# xslt stylesheet confirmation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this style-sheet and It's not working how intended and I am unsure where to go from here.

This is the XML:

```
<Root>
<CSMLData>
<GoProject>
<Project>
<Timeline>
<GenericMixer>
<Tracks>
<Medias>
<Callout>
<Attributes>
<Attribute>
<Parameter>
<Keyframes>
<Keyframe id="xx" value="Transparent Hotspot"/>
</Keyframes>
</Parameter>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Callout>
</Medias>
</Tracks>
</GenericMixer>
</Timeline>
</Project>
</GoProject>
</CSMLData>
</Root>
```

There are multiple children of type Keyframes inside Parameter, but only one Keyframe inside Keyframes for each.

This is the style-sheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Strip IMFile elements -->
    <xsl:template match="Callout[descendant::Keyframe/@value='Transparent Hotspot']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The outcome should remove the parent Callout and all of it's children so everything inside Callout if the condition is met should be removed.

Comment: Please post a well-formed example of the input XML, as well as the expected output - see [mcve].

Comment: I checked your sources using _xsltransform.net_ with _Xalan_ engine and it works OK. One more remark: Add _<xsl:output indent="yes"/>_. Otherwise the _Root_ tag is in the same line with _<?xml ...?>_ row.
Or use _<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>_ to eliminate _<?xml ...?>_.

Comment: Has your actual XML got a default namespace declaration on it, by any chance? i.e Does it have `xmlns="..."` on the root element?

Comment: No it does not have xmlns on the root element. If you say it works I must've applied it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was user error. I was using this this apply the style-sheet using Java. Below is the code that worked for me.

```
private void removeTransparentHotspots(){
        XMLReader readerXML = null;
        try {
            readerXML = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        // Load the transformer definition from the file strip.xsl:
        InputStream i = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("strip.xsl");
        Transformer t = null;
        try {
            t = tf.newTransformer(new SAXSource(readerXML, new InputSource(i)));
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            t.transform(new SAXSource(readerXML, new InputSource(new FileInputStream(getFile()))), new StreamResult(getFile()+"-tmp"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Once everything is complete, delete old file..
        File tempFile = new File(getFile());
        tempFile.delete();

        // And rename tmp file's name to old file name
        File newFile = new File(getFile()+"-tmp");
        newFile.renameTo(tempFile);
    }
```